# UWP - CommandBar : more button is "hidden"

Tags: uwp, template10, commandbar

I have an issue with command bar:
I use template10, so my CommandBar is in a Grid on bottom of page. I set the property ClosedDisplayMode to Minimal. But the grid has a Visibility=Collapsed by default.
When I switch the grid visibility to Visible, the CommandBar appears but the more button is not visible, the command bar is empty. However, the more button is here because I can click it. And when I have click on it at least one time, the content of the button ("...") appears.
I hope this is clear...

**EDIT 2**

Here is the way to reproduce issue:

1 - Create new blank universal app project (without template10)

2 - Replace the XAML code in MainPage.xaml by the following:

```
<Page
x:Class="BlankAppBarMoreButtonHidden.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:BlankAppBarMoreButtonHidden"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Show app bar"
            x:Name="btnShowAppBar"
            Click="btnShowAppBar_Click"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1"
          x:Name="appBar"
          Visibility="Collapsed">
        <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal">
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Label="Commande 1"/>
                <AppBarButton Label="Commande 2"/>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

3 - Add event implementation in the code behind:

```
private void btnShowAppBar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    appBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

4 - Finally, run the project. And press the button. The command bar appears but the more button is not visible. However you click it (clicking on its expected place in bottom right of page) and at this moment, the content appears.

Comment: Why do you need CommandBar in Grid? By Default Command Bar will be either at top or Bottom.

Comment: I made a basic demo, but didn't reproduce your problem. Could you post some codes about your project.

Comment: @AVKNaidu With hamburger template of template10, when you place the commandbar in "Page.BottomAppBar", the bottom part of the Navigation area is hidden by the commandbar.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I posted a part of code as Edit. In my side I will try to reproduce issue in blank project

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Okay, so I replaced my precedent edit by the way to reproduce issue in a blank universal app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a demo from your codes and reproduced the problem with my Windows 10 PC (build 10586).

Then I tested it again on another PC with Windows 10 Insider Preview build 14388. It turns out this problem has been fixed on Insider Preview build 14388.

You are welcome to join [Windows Insider Program](https://insider.windows.com/) and give us feedback that can help us make improvements.

Comment: Thanks Elvis, it's a good news. But I joined the Windows Insider Program with my mobile (just before the migration to Windows 10 Mobile). Today my coinfiguration is:
OS : 10.0.10586.494
Microprogram: 02540.00019.15236.45008
And I still have this problem

Comment: Yes, I can also reproduce this problem on OS: 10.0.10586. But 10.0.10586 is a lower version compared with OS: 10.0.14388. And on 10.0.14388 this problem doesn't occur. So, what I mean is if you update your OS to Insider Preview Build 14388 or other higher version, this problem will be gone.

Comment: Notes:After you joining the Windows Insider Program, there is a few days' delay for Notification on the latest OS Update.

Comment: OKay, thanks for your help. We can consider this subject as resolved :)